# Terraform: Convert a list of maps into a revised list of maps

Tags: arrays, list, dictionary, object, terraform

My input is:

```
input = [
  {
    x = "X1"
    y = "Y1"
  },
  {
    x = "X2"
    y = "Y2"
  },
  {
    x = "X3"
    y = "Y3"
  },
]
```

My desired output is:

```
output = [
  {
    val         = "X1",
    description = "This is a value of X"
  },
  {
    val         = "Y1",
    description = "This is a value of Y"
  },
  {
    val         = "X2",
    description = "This is a value of X"
  },
  {
    val         = "Y2",
    description = "This is a value of Y"
  },
  {
    val         = "X3",
    description = "This is a value of X"
  },
  {
    val         = "Y3",
    description = "This is a value of Y"
  },
]
```

How can this be achieved in Terraform?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the `flatten()` function in terraform for this:

```
flatten([
  for a_map in var.input : [
    { val = a_map.x, description = "This is a value of X" },
    { val = a_map.y, description = "This is a value of Y" },
  ]
])
```

An **advantage** of this approach is that it will maintain the order of values.

So the output will be:

```
[
  {
    "description" = "This is a value of X"
    "val" = "X1"
  },
  {
    "description" = "This is a value of Y"
    "val" = "Y1"
  },
  {
    "description" = "This is a value of X"
    "val" = "X2"
  },
  {
    "description" = "This is a value of Y"
    "val" = "Y2"
  },
  {
    "description" = "This is a value of X"
    "val" = "X3"
  },
  {
    "description" = "This is a value of Y"
    "val" = "Y3"
  },
]
```

Comment: That's nice way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The following produces such output:

```
variable "input" {

  default = [
    {
      x = "X1"
      y = "Y1"
    },
    {
      x = "X2"
      y = "Y2"
    },
    {
      x = "X3"
      y = "Y3"
    },
  ]

}



locals  {
  part1 = [for v in var.input:
      {
        "val" = v.x,
        "description" = "This is a value of X"
      }]
      
  part2 = [for v in var.input:
      {
        "val" = v.y,
        "description" = "This is a value of Y"
      }]      
}



output "output" {

  value = concat(local.part1, local.part2)

}
```

The output from my tests:

```
utput = [
  {
    "description" = "This is a value of X"
    "val" = "X1"
  },
  {
    "description" = "This is a value of X"
    "val" = "X2"
  },
  {
    "description" = "This is a value of X"
    "val" = "X3"
  },
  {
    "description" = "This is a value of Y"
    "val" = "Y1"
  },
  {
    "description" = "This is a value of Y"
    "val" = "Y2"
  },
  {
    "description" = "This is a value of Y"
    "val" = "Y3"
  },
]
```

Comment: This produces the map items correctly. But it does not maintain the same ordering of array items.

Comment: @Rakib No problem. The question did not say the ordering is of any concern. But anyway, thanks for letting me know. I see you found an answer :-)

Comment: The question mentioned the array as the desired output. And in arrays, the indexes are part of it :)

Comment: @Rakib Fair enough.